# "until late afternoon": when is that?

Tags: meaning

Here is a phrase about supermarkets in Belgium:

> The idea for brewing with bread came when 31-year-old Frenchman
>   Sebastien Morvan talked to a friend about food waste, specifically the
>   bread thrown away because supermarkets, eager to offer fresh bread to
>   shoppers all day, baked **until late afternoon.**

My question is: what does this *until * mean? Does it include "late afternoon" or not? Can we say that the process of baking ends around 5-6 pm?

(I need to understand it because I am translating it into Russian and we don't have the notion of "late afternoon", so I have to figure out the time :))

Thanks in advance!

/source: The Manitoba Co-operator, April 23, 2015/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In England I would say up to about 4-5 pm.

It's deliberately vague.

Comment: I agree, around 5pm seems to be the norm in the uk - which is probably the same as belgium - past that time and I would start using the word "evening".

Comment: Found a reference which supports this answer: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/parts-of-the-day-early-morning-late-morning-etc

Comment: The 4:00 cut-off is too early.  If someone told you to call anytime in the late afternoon, you'd expect that person to be in until 5:00 (or at least until 4:55), and would be annoyed if he were not.

Comment: For a lot of us, it would also vary with the season.  Hereabouts, "late afternoon" might be 3-4 pm in the winter, 6-7 pm in the summer.